# How to extract the sign, mantissa and exponent from a 32-Bit float

Tags: c, sign, exponent, mantissa

so I got a task where I have to extract the sign, exponent and mantissa from a floating point number given as uint32_t. I have to do that in C and as you might expect, how do I do that ?

For the sign I would search for the MSB (Most Significant Bit, since it tells me whether my number is positive or negative, depending if it's 0 or 1)

Or let's get straight to my idea, can I "splice" my 32 bit number into three parts ?

Get the 1 bit for msb/sign
Then after that follows 1 byte which stands for the exponent
and at last 23 bits for the mantissa

It probably doesn't work like that but can you give me a hint/solution ?
I know of freexp, but I want an alternative, where I learn a little more of C.
Thank you.

Comment: apply bitwise operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the bitwise layout of your floating point type (e.g. because your implementation supports IEEE floating point representations) then convert a pointer to your floating point variable (of type `float`, `double`, or `long double`) into a pointer to `unsigned char`.  From there, treat the variable like an array of `unsigned char` and use bitwise opertions to extract the parts you need.

Otherwise, do this;

```
  #include <math.h>

  int main()
  {
       double x = 4.25E12;   /* value picked at random */

       double significand;
       int exponent;
       int sign;

       sign = (x >= 0) ? 1 : -1;    /*  deem 0 to be positive sign */
       significand = frexp(x, &exponent);
  }
```

The calculation of `sign` in the above should be obvious.

`significand` may be positive or negative, for non-zero `x`.  The absolute value of `significand` is in the range `[0.5,1)` which, when multiplied by `2` to the power of `exponent` gives the original value.

If `x` is `0`, both `exponent` and `significand` will be `0`.

This will work regardless of what floating point representations your compiler supports (assuming `double` values).

Comment: For the first part, do you mean if you have `float x`, and `float* p_x = (float*) &x`.. how do you convert it to pointer to `unsigned char`? Like this : `unsigned char* ucp_x = (unsigned char*) p_x`?

Comment: Then how would you access it "like an array"?

Comment: If you need to ask that, you don't understand the relationship between arrays and pointers.   Any basic C text book describes that.

Comment: I know how to index an array/pointer, but I'm asking how casting it to `unsigned char' gives you the representation in that form, and which  indices represent what.

Comment: Casting to an `unsigned char *` allows treating the memory occupied by the floating point variable like an array (of `sizeof float` characters in your example).    As to what the individual characters mean, note the opening words of my answer "If you know the bitwise layout of your floating point type ...."